# Replace a user defined list of values with new values in linux

Tags: linux

I am having a list of values which I would want to look up in a large file, and if it matches then would want to add a prefix to the value.
for eg.

```
this is my list
19:16842551
18:16843048
16:16845373
```

and would want to look in a file that has these values

```
19:16842551 19  rs1 0.25
18:16843048 19  rs2 0.43
16:16845373 19  rs3 0.48
chr10:10000207 10   rs6 0.25
```

and convert them to

```
chr19:16842551  19  rs1 0.25
chr18:16843048  19  rs2 0.43
chr16:16845373  19  rs3 0.48
chr10:10000207 10   rs6 0.25
```

I can use the following command to do it - but by changing the number every single time

```
awk -v "OFS=\t" '{$1=$1;sub(/i*19:/, "chr19:", $1); print}' source.txt > temp.txt &&
mv temp.txt source.txt
```

Is this possible to give a variable $i to the list and change it altogether.

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: http://www.brunolinux.com/02-The_Terminal/Find_and%20Replace_with_Sed.html Do them individually. It should only be 3 runs of a sed

Comment: In my original list, I have around 22 runs.. and the source file is also so huge ...!!!

Comment: If you did it the long way it would've be done already. Just do each one (i.e. sed will find and replace all with each instruction) but if you want to learn something you can write a shell script. http://www.howtogeek.com/67469/the-beginners-guide-to-shell-scripting-the-basics/